# Discord.js - How do you use messageDeleteBulk from the Client class?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm setting up logging with my Discord bot and I'm trying to figure out how to log bulk deletes, but I don't know how I would actually code it. Here's an example from another bot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS6N1.jpg

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to replicate the example you gave in your question.

## Demonstration

[image: Discord bulk delete demonstration]

## Code

```js
client.on('messageDeleteBulk', async messages => {
  const length = messages.array().length;
  const channel = messages.first().channel.name;

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${length} Messages purged in #${channel}`)
    .setDescription(messages.map(message => `[${message.author.tag}]: ${message.content}`))
    .setFooter(`${length} latest shown`)
    .setColor('#dd5f53')
    .setTimestamp();

  // use this to send the message to the channel the bulk delete happened in 
  messages.first().channel.send(embed);
  // alternatively, use this to send the message to a specific channel
  (await client.channels.fetch(/* channel ID */)).send(embed);
});
```

**References:**

- [`messageDeleteBulk` event](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageDeleteBulk)
- [`MessageEmbed` constructor](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

Comment: My pleasure .